# Can't find how to convert FreeSansBold18pt7b.h to FreeSansBold18pt7b.bdf

Tags: c++, c, fonts, adafruit

I was developing on arduino with Adafruit-GFX-Library and do FreeSansBold18pt7b.h
[FreeSansBold18pt7b.h](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/master/Fonts/FreeSansBold18pt7b.h)

Now I develop on a Raspberry pi and with [rpi-rgb-led-matrix](https://github.com/hzeller/rpi-rgb-led-matrix).

I can’t find them in the format .bdf

Could you help me ?

Thx you

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-GFX-Library/blob/master/Fonts/FreeSansBold18pt7b.h

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't link to a bunch of code which isn't needed. Give us the minimal code which has something to do with your problem (I don't think that these constants of the file are a problem or am I missunderstanding something?) What do you want to achieve? What do you mean with "I can't find them in the format .bdf"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.